# I am creating a program in python what files should i add to gitignore?

Tags: python, git, github, gitignore, git-bash

I am currently writing a program in python however before I fully start I set up my git repository so I want to know what are the files that should be added to gitignore before I push to Github.
Not adding the correct files in previous projects caused me many problems, therefore, I am trying to avoid the same mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one got repository for various of gitignores on github.

[Python.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this nice repository: https://github.com/github/gitignore

It's a list of gitignore templates for many languages and frameworks.

Here is the one for python: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore